# CSS Equivalent of the WPF LinearGradientBrush and RadialGradientBrush?

Tags: html, wpf, css, linear-gradients

What would be the **CSS equivalent** of the following XAML LinearGradientBrush and RadialGradientBrush?

```
<LinearGradientBrush
    StartPoint="0.5,0"
    EndPoint="0.5,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF484848"
                  Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FF3b3b3b"
                  Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FF484848"
                  Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<RadialGradientBrush>
    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5"
                            CenterY="0.5"
                            ScaleX="2.6630001068115234"
                            ScaleY="2.3280000686645508" />
            <SkewTransform CenterX="0.5"
                           CenterY="0.5" />
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5"
                             CenterY="0.5" />
            <TranslateTransform X="0.51399999856948853"
                                Y="0.61900001764297485" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
    <GradientStop Color="#19FFFFFF"
                  Offset="1" />
    <GradientStop Color="#19FFFFFF"
                  Offset="0.85699999332427979" />
    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                  Offset="0.84799998998641968" />
</RadialGradientBrush>
```

The below image is the **sample output** :

[image: Example Image]

Comment: An empty CSS. There's no visible element, so you can't apply styling to it

Comment: @Chris: I don't know WPF but the equivalent linear gradient should be the one in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9d1u2a7/). I am totally lost on the radial gradients. Can you maybe show us an image of the output?

Comment: @Harry just uploaded an example image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CSS Equivalent for the WPF LinearGradientBrush:**

```xml
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF484848" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FF3b3b3b" Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FF484848" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

This code says the following things about the linear gradient:

- The gradient starts at `(0.5,0)` and ends at `(0.5,1)`. `(0,0)` and `(1,1)` are the default values for these properties and they point to top-left and bottom-right corners. So `(0.5,0)` should mean that gradient **starts** at `50%` on the **X-axis**, `0%` on **Y-axis** and **ends** at `50%` on the **X-axis**, `100%` on **Y-axis**. Thus, it is a horizontal gradient which goes from top `to bottom`.
- Based on the details provided [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-lineargradientbrush/) (refer to the last part), it seems like the gradients repeat itself to cover the parent container.
- The **color-stop points** in the gradient are at `0%`, 0.5 (which is `50%`) and 1 (which is `100%`) and the colors seem to be provided in `#AARRGGBB` format which would indicate that the `alpha` is `1`.

Based on these points, the equivalent CSS linear gradient code would be the following:

```css
.lineargrad{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #484848 0%, #3b3b3b 50%, #484848 100%);
}
```

```css
.lineargrad{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #484848 0%, #3b3b3b 50%, #484848 100%);
}
div{
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='lineargrad'></div>
```

---

**CSS Equivalent for the WPF RadialGradient Brush:**

```xml
<RadialGradientBrush>
    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="2.6630001068115234" ScaleY="2.3280000686645508" />
            <SkewTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
            <TranslateTransform X="0.51399999856948853" Y="0.61900001764297485" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
    <GradientStop Color="#19FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
    <GradientStop Color="#19FFFFFF" Offset="0.85699999332427979" />
    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.84799998998641968" />
</RadialGradientBrush>
```

This code says the following things about the radial gradient:

- **Center point and radius** aren't specified and so they are assumed to be `(0.5, 0.5)` which are the default values.
- **Color-stop points** for the gradient seems to be (*approximately*) at `84.79%`, `85.69%` and `100%`. The colors are again assumed to be in `#AARRGGBB` format.
- The `TransformGroup` (I think) indicates that this gradient image is **scaled** by `266%` in the **X-axis**, `232%` in **Y-axis** and is **translated** by `51.4%` in **X-axis**, `61.9%` in **Y-axis**. While we can achieve scaling in CSS by setting the `background-size`, there is no simple way to achieve the translate transform for gradient image alone and we have to just play around with position.

The following code is the closest that I could get to converting WPF's RadialGradientBrush to its CSS equivalent.

```css
.radialgrad {
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at 101.3% 111.9%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 84.79%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 85.69%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 100%);
  background-size: 266% 232%;
}
```

```css
.radialgrad {
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at 101.3% 111.9%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 84.79%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 85.69%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 100%);
  background-size: 266% 232%;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class='radialgrad'></div>
```

---

If a combination of the `linear-gradient` output and the `radial-gradient` output is needed then we can apply both values to `background-image` in comma separated format. CSS is capable of handling multiple layers of background images and the one specified at the end becomes the bottom-most layer.

```css
.combo {
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at 101.3% 111.9%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 84.79%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 85.69%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #484848 0%, #3b3b3b 50%, #484848 100%);
  background-size: 266% 232%, 100% 100%;
}
```

```css
.combo {
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at 101.3% 111.9%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 84.79%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 85.69%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #484848 0%, #3b3b3b 50%, #484848 100%);
  background-size: 266% 232%, 100% 100%;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='combo'></div>
```

Comment: As I remember multi-background is not supported in all versions of browsers, so it is worth noting about that (I know there is another solution using pseudo-element such as `:before`, ...).

Comment: Yes, but the support is pretty decent considering that it [works in IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) and IE8 support is already being dropped by MS themselves from Jan '16.

Comment: @Chris Very glad that you found it helpful :)